# Phabricator Differential integration with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, phabricator, arcanist

Does anyone know if it is possible to integrate the Differential workflow of Phabricator into the IntelliJ IDE?

Ideally I would like to be able to create, update, apply and commit a Diff directly from the Intellij IDE rather than resorting to the CLI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the best I found for your use case is this one:

https://github.com/halfmatthalfcat/TeamCity-Phabricator-Plugin

It is not maintained since 2020, but maybe you can use it to start something.